# Moving/Rolling Average in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, moving-average

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Consider the following table with three columns: `issueid`, `date` and `rate`: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/611682

The result I am looking for is:

[image]

For issueid 1, the average on 3/31/2014 is the average of the rate values on 01/31/2014, 02/28/2014 and 3/31/2014. In other words, for each security and at each the date, the moving average is the average of the rate values for that month and the two previous months.

**I would like the result to be dumped in a new column of the table.**

Is there any way to do that in an efficient way?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?, this is fairly trivial since SQL Server 2012

Comment: Sorry I hadn't mentioned that. SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle with the sample data instead of the image?

Comment: Here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/611682

Comment: One small add, I would like to have the result dumped in a new column of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.issueid, A.[date], A.rate, AVG(B.rate)
FROM test_table A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT *
             FROM test_table
             WHERE issueid = A.issueid
             AND [date] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-2,A.[date]) AND A.[date]) B 
GROUP BY A.issueid, A.[date], A.rate
ORDER BY A.issueid, A.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, if it is always a 3 month rolling, using SQL 2005 can't think of a more efficient way

```
SELECT  r.IssueId, r.date, (r.rate + r1.rate +r2.rate) /3 AS AvgRate
FROM    dbo.Rates AS r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT    Rates.IssueId,
                                Rates.date,
                                Rates.rate
                      FROM      Rates ) r1 ON r1.IssueId = r.IssueId AND r1.date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,r.date),0)),1)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT    Rates.IssueId,
                                Rates.date,
                                Rates.rate
                      FROM      Rates ) r2 ON r2.IssueId = r.IssueId AND r2.date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,r1.date),0)),1)
```